# PDF.js on Firefox

Tags: firefox, pdf

So I'm currently running Firefox 25 on Ubuntu 13.10, which is supposed to have the PDF reader in-built. I had the add-on when Mozilla released it a while back when it was being experimented, and now when I disable it, I'm unable to open any PDF documents - they all get downloaded instead. I have "Preview in Firefox" set as the default action for PDF files, the value of `pdfjs.disabled` is `false` and that of `plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types` is `application/pdf`.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: **Remove** the PDF Viewer add-on via **Tools** (Alt + T) > **Add-ons** > **Extensions**, and restart Firefox. If the Remove button is unavailable please see [Removing global extensions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Cannot%20uninstall%20an%20add-on#w_globally-installed-extensions).

[Disable or Remove Add-ons](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-or-remove-add-ons)

Comment: I've already tried that; as I said, PDF documents don't open, they download instead when I remove the extension.

Comment: Can you also please check the **Action** for **Portable Document Format (PDF)** in Edit > Preferences > [Applications](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/set-how-firefox-handles-different-file-types)? Ideally it should be Preview in Firefox.

Comment: Also, the [Content-Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header#Responses) of the PDF file as sent by the site/server should be application/pdf. You can check the Content-Type via Firefox Tools > Web Developer > [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console); browse to the site, open the web console, clear any current entries, click/download the PDF, and in the web console click on the GET link corresponding to the PDF link and check the Content-Type under Response Headers.

Comment: As I said, "Preview in Firefox" is the option. And the Content-Type header is `application/pdf`

Comment: Ok, if you haven't already tried a [new profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles), please do so. If the new profile is okay, you can delete it and then [Reset Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems) from the old profile to get a new profile with automatic migration of personal data. Also, make sure that there are no default extensions (Ctrl-Shift-A) in the new profile.

Comment: A new profile should definitely work unless there is a problem with the current Firefox installation/upgrades. Also note that **Disable** and **Remove** in the Add-ons Manager (Ctrl-Shift-A) are different actions; in some scenarios Remove may not be available.

Comment: Remove is available; I've tried both. I'd rather not start with a new profile since I've been using my current one for several years and it's been configured very carefully. Are there maybe some files I could remove/folders I can clean up instead?

Comment: I understand your concerns. You could try the new profile once to make sure, and then immediately delete it (via [Profile Manager](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Manager)), and return to the old (current) profile/settings as before. From there a good method would be checking in [Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) and exiting, without making any changes.

Comment: For the details about the [profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder) contents please see [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox). Also, a reference for **Important Modified Preferences** (about:config, and Edit > Preferences) can be obtained via Firefox Help (Alt + H) > Troubleshooting Information.